# Dynamically changing number of columns in React Native Flat List

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a `FlatList` where I want to change the number of columns based on orientation. However, I get the red screen when I do this. As per the red screen error message, I'm not quite sure how I should be changing the key prop. Any help is appreciated.

```
      // dynamically changing number of columns
      const numCols = orientation === constants.PORTRAIT ? 3 : 8

      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(_, i) => i}
        numColumns={numCols} // assigning the number of columns
        horizontal={false}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <ListItem imageUrl={item.url} />}
      />}
```

[image: red screen of death]

Answer (score 58, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html), looks like you should do something like this

```
key={(this.state.horizontal ? 'h' : 'v')}
```

Comment: key attribute thing worked for me, but upon re-render the header flickers as it's static and same for both instances of the list

Comment: this kinda works .. however list will be rerendered and scroll position will initiate from the start

Comment: Why not just use numColumns as key?

Answer (score 39):

I did it using **key**

```
  <FlatList
    numColumns = {this.state.columnCount}
    key={this.state.columnCount}
  />
```

Comment: Came here to add something like this to the answers looks like you've done it already ;)

Comment: a random key works as well `key={Math.random().toString()}`

Answer (score 9):

## In Hooks

```
const [numCols, setColumnNo] = useState(0);

<FlatList
key={numCols}
numColumns={numCols}
...
/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Pass a changing value to the FlatList itself. It has nothing to do with the keyExtractor or the key attrbibute in renderItem methods:

```
<FlatList key={changingValue} .. />
```

should solve it.

Answer (score 3):

```
<FlatList
         data={props.localFolders}
         style={{ width: "100%" }}
         numColumns={4}
         key={4}
         renderItem={({ item }) => <LocalFolder {...item} />}
         keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
/>
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

I think the message is very clear. You need to define different keys for portrait/landscape if you want to change the number of columns to force a fresh re-render. Try concatenating the `numCols` value to the index in your `keyExtractor`.

Comment: @scooper, thanks for replying. I did exactly what you mentioned, but still get the error.  https://gist.github.com/foobar8675/cbeb30b00d2c6c475eac378c52833503#file-gistfile1-txt-L76 .  I uploaded a gist and am pretty confused. (initially I did something very similar to your suggestion, which did not work, which is why I thought I did not understand the error message.

Comment: Like the solution posted, it may be the key of the flat list itself that needs to be specified to trigger a fresh re render on the list rather than just the cells

Comment: Nope this is wrong, you're supposed to re-render the flatlist not the items in the flatlist

Answer (score 0):

**If you need to make your app responsive when is landscape mode, try this:**

```
     const {height, width} = useWindowDimensions();
     const isLandscape = width > height;

     <FlatList
     numColumns={Number(isLandscape) + 1}
     keyExtractor={item => item.id}
     key={Number(isLandscape)}
     ...
```

This will convert boolean into number.
**Note** *useWindowDimensions* is imported from react-native.