# Is it impossible to use 2 FlatList which have different numColumns each other in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Is the following code impossible?
I'd like to make these 2 lists different to each other.

```
{
    this.state.displayStage ?

        <FlatList
            numColumns={2}           //  If I remove this, it works well.
            data={this.props.topPlayed ? this.props.topPlayed.otherArtist : []}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <View style={styles.borderImageGroup}>
                    <Image style={styles.borderImage} source={{ uri: item['thumbnailURL'] }} />
                </View>
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />

        :

        <FlatList
            horizontal                   //  ---->
            data={this.props.topPlayed ? this.props.topPlayed.otherArtist : []}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <View style={styles.borderImageGroup}>
                    <Image style={styles.borderImage} source={{ uri: item['thumbnailURL'] }} />
                </View>
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />
}
```

Then I got the following error.
"Invariant Violation: Changing numColumns on the fly is not supported. Change the key prop on FlatList when changing he number of columns to force a fresh render of the component."
What is the reason and what is solution?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself.
That is the reference URL: [Dynamically changing number of columns in React Native Flat List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291781/dynamically-changing-number-of-columns-in-react-native-flat-list)

Add the following to the FlatList

```
    numColumns = {this.state.columnCount}
    key={this.state.columnCount}
```