# Invariant Violation: Changing numColumns on the fly is not supported. I do not change though

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

```
{
   selected.length == 2 
   ?
   <FlatList
   keyExtractor={item => "_" + item.id}
   renderItem={this.renderLastItem}
   data={subGroups}
   numColumns={1} /> 
   :
   <FlatList
   keyExtractor={item => "#" + item.id}
   renderItem={this.renderItem}
   data={subGroups}
   numColumns={2} />
}
```

In the above lines of code when `selected.length` equals 2, I get the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: Changing numColumns on the fly is not supported.
```

These are two different lists and I am not changing numColumns. It seems to me that react native is trying to use the same object of FlatList in all conditions. How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This question has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291781/dynamically-changing-number-of-columns-in-react-native-flat-list). I am not sure exactly why this error is thrown. But with all the optimizations around rendering that are implemented on `FlatList`, it might have been a decision taken by RN team to throw this error.

As described in the answer to linked question, you'll need to add keys to the `FlatList` in order to help React-Native refresh the component on `selected` value change.

You can fix it by doing

```
{selected.length == 2 ?
<FlatList
   key={'_'}
   keyExtractor={item => "_" + item.id}
   renderItem={this.renderLastItem}
   data={subGroups}
   numColumns={1} /> 
   :
<FlatList
   key={'#'}
   keyExtractor={item => "#" + item.id}
   renderItem={this.renderItem}
   data={subGroups}
   numColumns={2} />
}
```

Github issue raised similar to this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15944

Comment: No need for using two flatlists just set numColumns to the key as well.

Comment: Best Answer! safe my day! Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I added just this in my single flatlist and it worked:

key={'_'}

Comment: In My case, I have solved it by just setting `horizontal={false}` as suggested by


  [1]: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#numcolumns